# How to display the Date time from timeval in c++

Tags: c++

I am using timeval throughout my project. I want to display Date and time like, Sep 15, 2010 - 11:10 using the available timeval object. Is there any way to do it or can I get time_t from the available timeval.

Thanks.

Comment: timeval defines a time interval - you cannot convert this to an absolute time.  Do you have a baseline time relative to which you want to convert?

Answer (score 0):

I got it, timeval has time_t as a member so I can get that time_t from that and then using many available functions to display date.